# Bidirectioal search in Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have come upon a problem in our application using Hibernate Search.

We have a class, A where we do hsearch against fields in class A and B and also Spatial search agaist class Address declared in A. 
Everything works nicely.

Now we have to implement search the other way around also, we want to search class B for fields contained in B, A and spatial search  against A.Address. Now we have a problem. Since
B has A declared as `@ContainedIn`, the fields of A isn't searcheable from B.
If we change `@ContainedIn` to `@IndexEmbedded` we get circular dependency because you can't have `@IndexEmbedded` on both sides.
Then I read that you can limit the depth on `@IndexEmbedded` so I tried that. I know that we aren't going to search deeper than A.?.?.? in B so I changed `@ContainedIn` to 
`@IndexEmbedded(depth = 4)` on class A in class B.

Now when I start my application I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000158: Class Address
>   cannot have two @Spatial using default/same name

Has anyone any tips on how to solve this?
We use Hibernate Search version 4.5.0.Final 
Se the classes below.
Regards 
Andreas

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@FullTextFilterDefs({
        @FullTextFilterDef(name = "externalSearchFilterFactory", impl = ExternalSearchFilterFactory.class),
        @FullTextFilterDef(name = "internalSearchFilterFactory", impl = InternalSearchFilterFactory.class)
})
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
@Table(name = "A")
public class A extends DomainObjekt {

    .....

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private B b;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Address adress;

    .....

} 


@Entity
@Indexed
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
@Table(name = "B")
public class B extends DomainObjekt {

    .....

    @ContainedIn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private Set<A> listOfA = new HashSet<A>();

    .....
}

@Spatial(name = "location", spatialMode = SpatialMode.RANGE)
@Indexed
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@SuppressWarnings({"serial"})
public class Address extends DomainObjekt {

    .....

    @Latitude(of = "location")
    @Column(name = "LATITUDE")
    private Double latitude;

    @Longitude(of = "location")
    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
    private Double longitude;

    .....
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem. By using includePaths in class A and naming just the fields I was interested in, I got rid of the circular dependency that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The *@Spatial* annotation takes a *name* attribute.
You should use this attribute when you want to have multiple spatial fields in the same entity, so that you can point to a specific one when doing queries.

Comment: I have already tried that, same result. The problem is that I'm seraching a list of objects as you can see above which each contain an address and this doesn't seem to work. I had to do a workaround by creating my own class for calculating distances based on the Haversine formula and I'm using that in a filter instead of using Hibernate Spatial serach.